# Does this Arboretum Rooftop Building exist?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

In Uchouten Kazoku, episode 06, there is this scene. Does this building exist?

[image: Arboretum Rooftop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual rooftop garden does not seem to exist, but there is a likely model for this building, which is located northwest of [this temple](https://www.google.co.jp/maps?q=%E5%85%AD%E8%A7%92%E5%A0%82%E9%A0%82%E6%B3%95%E5%AF%BA&hl=ja&ie=UTF8&ll=35.007713,135.760255&spn=0.000922,0.001671&sll=35.02334,135.752764&sspn=0.235887,0.42778&brcurrent=3,0x6001089aca8356fd:0x9d248930a86f0a64,0&hq=%E5%85%AD%E8%A7%92%E5%A0%82%E9%A0%82%E6%B3%95%E5%AF%BA&t=h&z=20).

[image: Rooftop Garden]

It seems to be a private building this is a school that teaches Ikebana/華道. It's likely this rooftop area is not open to the public. This seems to be the closest match to the building depicted in the anime.